# How to recover from an apt-get bricked system

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I am on a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However,recently, when uninstalling some packages with `apt-get remove`, when I specified multiple packages (like `apt-get remove package1 package2 package3`) where **none** of them were system packages, for whatever reason, I noticed apt started removing weird packages like `power`. After a reboot, my OS install was bricked.

First of all, is `apt-get remove [multiple packages]` proper syntax? If so, what could have caused `apt` to suddenly randomly remove system packages? (This is not the first time that it has occurred!) I searched online, but couldn't find any conclusive results.

Second, is there an easy command (since I can still *boot* the os into rescue mode) that allows me to reinstall all system packages?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you remove a package (say package1), all packages that *depend* on package1 will also need to be removed so my guess is you removed packages that had *depends* rules applied to them, thus why you're shown the list of packages that will be removed as a consequence of your command and asked to confirm it. You haven't told us what you removed, nor given us any clue (*package1, package2* isn't very helpful in us understanding what you did). You should still be able to login to text terminal (unless you removed that too). Reads like operator error to me.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you removed; as you've given absolutely no indication, but your command `history` should reveal what commands you executed, or else there is the `apt` logs found in `/var/log/apt/history.log` which will dictate who, when & what changes were made including packages added/removed etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go look in the history.log file.

Comment: Also, I can't remember which packages I specifically uninstalled, but they were all related to `libimobiledevice`.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks @guiverc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @guiverc suggested, I looked through `/var/log/apt/history.log`, found the uninstall command that had bricked my install, and reinstalled everything under the "Removed" section.